# How can I avoid massive (waste) CPU usage by Mathematica?

Tags: parallelization

I am using *Mathematica* on a Linux machine with 52 CPUs. I am sending my jobs in a batch mode and I am not using any parallel evaluation like `ParallelTable[]` or so. Unfortunately *Mathematica* is massively using CPUs without any benefit in speed (one job uses up to 4000% CPU).
To reduce this waste CPU usage I want to limit the number of kernels each job can use to one. I tried `KernelLaunch[1]` and indeed

```
$KernelCount
```

is equal to one. However,

> $ConfiguredKernels

gives me

```
{SubKernels`LocalKernels`LocalMachine[16, SubKernels`LocalKernels`LowerPriority -> True]}
```

which I interpret that still 16 (sub)kernels are running leading to 1600% CPU usage. I also tried

```
SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 1]
```

but again with no success.

How can I configure *Mathematica* such that only 100% of CPU power is used for one job?

Comment: If you are not using `Parallel*` functions then only one kernel is running.  One kernel can make use of multiple CPU cores for certain functionality, e.g. linear algebra.  To control this, take a look at `SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]` and set the `MKLThreadNumber` and `ParallelThreadNumber`.

Comment: It worked with this:LaunchKernels[1];
SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 1];
SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "MKLThreadNumber" -> 1];
The command SetSystemOptions["MKLThreads" -> 1] is no longer working. The new one ist SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "MKLThreadNumber" -> 1]

Comment: @Volker probably you can post this as an answer including the code in [formatted form](https://wolfr.am/v57OLJu4).